# Issue with creating dynamic objects

Tags: c++, class, file-io, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am making a project where I need to create dynamic class objects.

```
void representative(){
int x;
pharmacy_personnel ob1;
A:
clrscr();
cout<<"Please select what you would like to do:"<<endl
    <<"1. Add Medicines to the pharmacy"<<endl
    <<"Enter your Choice >> ";cin>>x;

switch(x){
    case 1: {
        char y;
        fstream file(Fname,ios::in|ios::binary);
        pharmacy_personnel temp;
        while(file.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(temp)))
            total++;    

        A:
        clrscr();
        cout<<"Please fill in the fields required to add the medicine to the records"<<endl;
            temp.add_medicine(Fname);
            total++;// this is to get the total no. of records on the file
        *pharmacy_personnel *ob1;
        ob1=new pharmacy_personnel [total];

        for(int i=0; i<total; i++)
            file.read((char*)&ob1[i],sizeof(ob1));*

        B:
        cout<<"Do you want to add another medicine?(y/n): "; cin>>y;
            if(y=='y'||y=='Y')
                goto A;
            else
            if(y=='n'||y=='N')
                break;
            else
            {
            cout<<"Please Enter a valid response"<<endl;
            clrscr();
            goto B;
            }
        pharmacy_personnel *ob1;
        ob1=new pharmacy_personnel [total];

        } break;

        default: cout<<"Please choose from 1->5 only"<<endl; getch();
        goto A;

}
        delete ob1;   }
```

Total is a global variable

I want to know if there is a better way of doing the whole thing as the value of total will change very frequently
also how can I access these objects globally in another UDF?

Comment: Did you use C++ or C as programming language? Please add an appropiate tag to your question.

Comment: Maybe getting rid of `goto` will improve quality of this code.

Comment: Could you please suggest and alternative to goto?

Comment: Probably replacing goto with settings some flags to true, i.e. in the `Do you want to add another medicine?(y/n)`, you should do: `if(y=='y'||y=='Y') add_another_med = true` and then continue. At the end of the loop, you should check for these flags and take the needed actions.